# Splitting table with multiple columns into individual tables

Tags: css, html

I have a website with lots of tables that have 2-3 columns but I need to convert each column into its own table so they will stack up for the mobile site. I'm looking at a daunting amount of work at the moment.

Is there a way that I can split each column into its own table without doing all of it by hand? I'm working in code but would a WYSIWYG software allow me to do this perhaps? Or some other type of workaround?

```
<table class="dataTable">

                        <thead>
                            <tr>
                                <th>Hauptwerk</th>
                                <th>Brustwerk (expressive)</th>
                                <th>Pedal</th>
                            </tr>
                        </thead>
                        <tbody>
                            <tr>
                                <td>Prinzipal 8'</td>
                                <td>Gedackt 8'</td>
                                <td>Subbass 16'</td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td>Hohlflöte 8'</td>
                                <td>Rohrflöte 4'</td>
                                <td>Prinzipal 8'</td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td>Oktave 4'</td>
                                <td>Nazat 2-2/3'</td>
                                <td>Bourdon 8'</td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td>Flöte 2'</td>
                                <td>Prinzipal 2'</td>
                                <td>Oktave 4'</td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td>Mixtur IV</td>
                                <td>Terz 1-3/5'</td>
                                <td>Fagott 16'</td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td>Trompete 8'</td>
                                <td>Quinte 1-1/3'</td>
                                <td>&nbsp;</td>
                            </tr>

                            <tr>
                                <td>&nbsp;</td>
                                <td>Scharff III</td>
                                <td>&nbsp;</td>
                            </tr>

                            <tr>
                                <td>&nbsp;</td>
                                <td class="italic">Tremulant</td>
                                <td>&nbsp;</td>
                            </tr>
                        </tbody>
                    </table>
```

I'm not sure which part of the CSS would be relevant, here is a sample page:
http://letourneauorgans.com/en/opus121.php

Comment: There should be a bit of CSS that you can add to display tabular data properly on mobile.  Can we see your markup and CSS?

Comment: @AdamKonieska Added more details. If I could just add a bit of CSS that would be fantastic!

Comment: thanks!  When I emulate it as iphone6 in chrome, it doesn't look like there is a responsive mobile version, and I get the desktop version on my S5.  Both show the desktop site with all the tables in view.  I notice there is a responsive view for the homepage.  Should this page be using that as well?

Comment: looking further, it seems like the mobile version of that page was disabled.  When I remove the comments around <!--<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">--> it gives me the mobile version for that page, with the tables (great, swell, chior, pedal) displayed nicely.  Is that what you are looking for?

Comment: Maybe 2 columns wide displays fine on mobile but I'm worried about 3 columns of content. The audience for this is not that young so I don't want too much scaling on the text. I wanted to have Great, Swell, Choir, Pedal displayed individually, stacked over each other (which is why I wanted to split each column in its own table)

Comment: Ah, understood.  You can do that, but you will need to split up the tables.  You'll also need some div tags to group the tables (for when you want 2x2 on desktop, and 1x4 on mobile).  Those div tags will need some CSS so they know how to re-position for mobile.  Usually a CSS framework like bootstrap or foundation does this for you.  See this bootstrap example, and note how it shifts and stacks the columns when you resize the browser window:  https://getbootstrap.com/examples/grid/  You'll either need to write that CSS yourself, or use a CSS framework.

Comment: Yea the rest of my pages stack already, I was keeping this part for "dessert"... looks like I'll need to split it all up by hand. Ugh! Thanks for the help regardless :-)

Comment: I assume most HTML editors have commands for "Select table column" and then cut, and paste below the table. At least SeaMonkey's Composer has.